# My C# target code completely ignores vectors that are behind it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some rotation code in Unity to make a rigidbody rotate and point to a target on axis, however I've encountered a strange little issue where it ignores vectors that are directly behind it until the vector moves just a bit.

This is a minor problem as roughly half of the potential targets will be behind the moving vehicle using this code - on a 2.5D plane. This is the snippet as it currently exists. What needs to be fixed to acknowledge targets that are directly behind this?

```
    TargetLocation = TempTarget.position;
    Vector3 Heading = TargetLocation - transform.position;

    Vector3 Rotate = Vector3.Cross(-transform.up, (Heading).normalized) * 200;

    boatRB.AddTorque(Rotate);
```

Comment: You cannot use a Capital capitalization for a variable name.  You must change "TargetLocation" to "targetLocation".  Same for all your variables.

Comment: Further, you *must not* use "Rotate" as a variable name (nor "rotate"), since that is a call in Unity.

Comment: Note, in navigation, "heading" always means **the direction your own nose is pointing**.  "targetLocation - transform.position" would be more like "bearing".  If you are going to do physics programming, it is *absolutely essential* to get terminology correct, and also units.  I may misunderstand something in your set up, but you must change "heading" to "bearing"  or "directionToTarget".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue using a marker and rotation disc for my vehicle to follow when it turns. I originally wanted to purely use code for the issue, but this particular fix turned out to be far smoother and better in general, and it actually works better with my AI format.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is with torque as it doesn't work if you apply force in direction of axis of rotation. Which is in your case, when target is right behind the transform. So your `rotate` vector would be passing through axis of rotations. To overcome this problem, I would suggest that use dot product to find if the target is right behind the transform and use some different technique to rotate it. One good method can be using `Transform.LookAt`to rotate.

References:

- [Dot Product Application](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-vector3-dot-for-direction-facing-calculation.173707/)
- [Transform LookAt Method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

Comment: I can't do that - the code simulates a moving ship over water, and transform.lookat/other methods tend to break the buoyancy effects I currently have working. The only other way I can think of would be to apply exactly 180 degrees worth of torque along axis for the rotation effect.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat (or rotates your boat in this case lol).

Comment: I think I may have come up with a solution. It's really hack-ey, but Unity seems to call for several cases like this. Put the rotation target on a cylinder, spin the cylinder by 180 and have the vehicle follow the target. The cylinder stays exactly centered on the vehicle.

Comment: HI Merlin.  That is not hacky.  **That is exactly how you make video games.** I can't exactly follow what you're saying in your question. But it is 100% usual to have **"marker"** objects (in Unity specifically, simply, an empty `GameObject`) which moves around with other objects, and does exactly the sort of thing you describe.  I believe you have other problems (see answer) but it is totally correct and normal to have "marker" objects.  For boating simulations, you would have "marker" objects on an abstract flat plane, for various reasons, for every buoyant object.

Comment: With all due respect, I was originally looking for a purely code fix as I have done before. As for your other comments, frankly I have to wonder some. While "Rotate" was used (refined code since then), the scope of the variable was limited to just that particular little area, and I "MUST" use lowerUpper? Neither Unity or the IDE I use care  - it's purely a style choice. However, I am happy with my solution as it exists now.